# How to rotate a complex number in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation

I didn't find a response online for my question yet but as it is quite short and I'm sure, someone will have a solution here, I thought, I could try:

I would like to rotate a complex number (complex plane) by a certain degree in Matlab. Let's say, I have a matrix like

```
[-6.5100 - 3.6500i;
-6.3600 - 3.7800i;
-6.3400 - 3.8300i]
```

that represents trajectory data. How can I rotate its rows by e.g. 14 degrees in Matlab?

Many thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you mean rotate _each_ number, that's very basic maths. You multiply by `exp(j*theta)`, where `theta` is the desired angle. If you really want to rotate a row of complex numbers, you need to define what that is

Comment: Ah, perfect, that answers my question! I forgot the "exp". Many thanks, that was really helpful!